# "installing" Linux programmes

Tags: software-installation

I have read the forum on this and find the instructions on installing tar.gz files almost incomprehensible, with multiple conditions and caveats. Can anyone explain why this process is made so fiendishly complicated compared to Windows?

And No, I am not a beginner, but have used computers since their commercial infancy and also create my own websites and programme databases. I simply cannot understand why Linux programmers cannot come up with something more standard and understandable. Linux has so much going for it, but this critical area is enough to put off anyone but an expert. Is there some technical reason why it can't be simplified?

Comment: What program are you trying to install from a `tar.gz` file?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, have you ever used a linux man?

Comment: Have you tried running the Software Centre?

Answer (score 10):

Well, firstly, I don't think it's overly difficult to install applications in linux.

If you're simply trying to install a popular application in Ubuntu, you can use package management in your the graphical user interface.  There are many to pick from.  It really can't get any easier.  Find the application and click install...

When it comes to the prompt, once again, it's very easy to install, 'sudo apt-get install application-name'.

If you're trying to compile something from source, which is what I am assuming you're meaning in your "tar.gz" statement.  You ./configure ; make ; make install.  Keep in mind, .tar.gz is simply a compression, it's like saying install a .zip in windows.  The zip itself isn't the application, it just contains the application.  You could have a .tar.gz compress an install package.  You would decompress the .tar.gz and then run something like start.sh to install an already compiled binary, which would be similar to 'installing'.  Which is just a simple process of moving files, and linking them to dependencies, etc..

Once again, I don't find it hard to install any application using a GUI, whether it's windows or ubuntu.  However, if you're talking about compiling an application from source code, it's not really simply 'installing' and you're in a different league than windows.  In fact, windows out of the box can't compile.  It requires applications to be already compiled, and be shipped with the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

As @Brian already said, a `.tar.gz` is like a `.zip` file - just a compression.

`.tar.gz` (or any `.tar.*`) is a source code archive - you must compile it:

(In the Terminal)

1. Extract it. (`tar xvf filename.tar.gz`)
2. Change into the directory: (`cd filename/`)
3. If there is a file called `autogen` or `auotogen.sh`, run it.
4. If there is a file called `configure.sh`, run it.
5. Run `make`.
6. Run `sudo make install`.

Look at the project's documentation (install documentation found usually in a `README` file, probably included with the source code. This is because they may require additional things to be installed before compilation. They (or Ubuntu, or a PPA maintainer) may even provide a fully-built package.

P.S. If you install such source-only packages frequently, you may consider putting my [bash function](https://gist.github.com/bharadwaj-raju/9d26ebe7d5972731a3bb1bf96ca29f94) in your `~/.bashrc` file. Then you can just run `compile filename.tar.gz`.

P.P.S. I assure you, installing `.tar.gz` sources in Windows is *much, much* more complicated.